# Pandas Groupby, does not take selection into account

Tags: python, pandas

I am struggling for a while now with the Pandas grouping function.

**Explaination of data:**
In the code below I load a CSV file into a DataFrame. I had to preprocess the data to structure in a way that each column is a variable, before a column was a variable of a certain wave. The result DataFrame has over 120 variables and each variable has it's own column. Row wise is an observation. Each participant has between the 1 and 13 observations, uniquely identified by a ResponseID and wave number.

**Goal:**
In this experiment I have two scenario's, one for only the Dutch participants and one scenario for all participants from all over the world. I want to know the mean of the observations per participant for each variable, for both scenario's.

**Problem:**
Whenever I run this code, the shape of the group per ID is the same for both the Dutch Data scenario as for the World data scenario. While when i deterimine the amount of participants with the .unique() function of Pandas, it does exactly what i expect, namely a small number for the amount of Dutch participants and a large number for the world Data participants.

**Question:**
Can anyone help me solve this problem?

it states that I have a equal amount of participant for both the Dutch Data scenario as for the World data scenario.

**Preprocessing code**

```
import sklearn as sk
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

from sklearn.preprocessing import KBinsDiscretizer

# CSV Settings
seperator = ","
decimal='.'

# Input files
data_raw_file = {"path": "./data.csv", "sheet": None}
data_question_file = {"path": "./Variable Justification.xlsx", "sheet": "Full sheet"}

# View x lines of a table
view_lines = 10
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", view_lines, "display.max_columns", None)

# Load data
data = pd.read_csv(data_raw_file["path"], sep=seperator, decimal=decimal)

# Use
identifier_vars = ["ResponseId", "id"]
demographic_vars = ["age", "coded_country", "edu", "gender"]
outcome_vars = ["affAnx", "affBor", "affCalm", "affDepr", "affEnerg", "affNerv", "affExh", "affInsp", "affRel", "affAng", "affLov"]

# Types (Other variables are considered numerical)
discrete_vars = ["employstatus", "isoObjWho", "coronaClose", "houseLeaveWhy"]
orderd_categorical_vars = ["age", "edu"]
categorical_vars = ["coded_country", "gender", "ResponseId", "id"]

# Wave information
waves = pd.DataFrame(data = [["base"  , ""   , "Ongoing"],
                             ["wave01", "w1_", "1-3-2020"],
                             ["wave02", "w2_", "2-4-2020"],
                             ["wave03", "w3_", "3-5-2020"],
                             ["wave04", "w4_", "4-6-2020"], 
                    columns =["Waves" , "Wave_ref", "Date"])

# Extract the unique variable names, by making use of the general structure wx_varName, where x is the wave number.
# ================================================================
variable_names = data.keys().str.replace(r'(w\d*\_)', "").unique().to_frame(index=False, name="name")

# Define the different types of variable and their use
# ================================================================
variable_names["use"] = "IV"
variable_names.loc[variable_names["name"].isin(demographic_vars), "use"] = "Demographic"
variable_names.loc[variable_names["name"].isin(identifier_vars), "use"] = "Identifier"
variable_names.loc[variable_names["name"].isin(outcome_vars), "use"] = "DV"

variable_names["type"] = "Continuous"
variable_names.loc[variable_names["name"].isin(categorical_vars), "type"] = "Categorical"
variable_names.loc[variable_names["name"].isin(orderd_categorical_vars), "type"] = "Ordered_Categorical"
for var in discrete_vars:
    variable_names.loc[variable_names["name"].str.match('^' + var + '.*'), "type"] = "Discrete"

# Wave in to dataFrame
# ==============================================================
df_waves = pd.DataFrame(columns=variable_names["name"])

for idx, w_ref in enumerate(waves["Wave_ref"]):
    # Add Wx_ to the variable names    
    temp_var = [w_ref + s for s in variable_names[variable_names["type"].isin(["Continuous", "Discrete"])]["name"]] + demographic_vars + identifier_vars
    temp_df = data[data.columns.intersection(temp_var)].copy()
    temp_df.columns = [s.replace(str(w_ref), "") for s in temp_df.columns]  # Remove wave number from column
    temp_df["wave"] = waves[waves["Wave_ref"] == w_ref]["Waves"].values[0]
    temp_df["wave_date"] = waves[waves["Wave_ref"] == w_ref]["Date"].values[0]
    df_waves = df_waves.append(temp_df, ignore_index=True)

data = df_waves.copy()
del(df_waves, temp_df, temp_var, idx, w_ref)

# Define data types
# =================================================================
discrete_vars = variable_names[(variable_names["name"].isin(data.columns)) & (variable_names["type"] == "Discrete")]["name"]
data[discrete_vars] = data[discrete_vars].replace(1, True)
data[discrete_vars] = data[discrete_vars].fillna(value=False)
data[discrete_vars] = data[discrete_vars].astype(bool)

continuous_vars = variable_names[(variable_names["name"].isin(data.columns)) & (variable_names["type"] == "Continuous")]["name"]
data[continuous_vars] = data[continuous_vars].astype(float)

o_categorical_vars = variable_names[(variable_names["name"].isin(data.columns)) & (variable_names["type"] == "Ordered_Categorical")]["name"]
data[o_categorical_vars] = data[o_categorical_vars].astype(float)

continuous_vars = variable_names[(variable_names["name"].isin(data.columns)) & (variable_names["type"] == "Categorical")]["name"]
data[continuous_vars] = data[continuous_vars].astype("category")
```

**Part of code, where I think/thought the problem is** (comes after preprocessing)

```
p1_data = data.copy()

p1_scenarios = {"Dutch_Data" : p1_data[p1_data["coded_country"]=="Netherlands"],
                "World_Data": p1_data   
}

for i, scenario in enumerate(p1_scenarios):
   p1_data_scene = p1_scenarios[scenario]
   participants = 1_data_scene["ResponseId"].unique()    
   mean_per_id = p1_data_scene[outcome_vars+["ResponseId"]].groupby(by="ResponseId", dropna=False).mean()
   

print(scenario)
print(p1_data_scene.shape)
print("Amount of participants " + str(len(participants))) 
print("Shape of group per ID" + str(mean_per_id.shape))
```

**Example of the Data after preprocessing:**

| observation | affAnx | affBor | affCalm | affDepr | affEnerg | affNerv | affExh | affInsp | affRel | affAng | affLov | PLRAC19 | PLRAEco | disc01 | disc02 | disc03 | jbInsec01 | jbInsec02 | jbInsec03 | jbInsec04 | employstatus_1 | employstatus_2 | employstatus_3 | employstatus_14 | employstatus_4 | employstatus_5 | employstatus_11 | employstatus_12 | employstatus_6 | employstatus_7 | employstatus_8 | employstatus_9 | employstatus_10 | employstatus_13 | hours_worked_1 | PFS01 | fail01 | isoFriends_inPerson | isoOthPpl_inPerson | isoFriends_online | isoOthPpl_online | isoObj | isoObjWho_1 | isoObjWho_2 | isoObjWho_3 | isoObjWho_4 | isoObjWho_5 | isoObjWho_6 | houseTrad | discPers | lone01 | mentHealth | mentPhys | happy | lifeSat | MLQ | JWB_1 | tightNorms | tightLoose | tightTreat | probSolving01 | probSolving02 | probSolving03 | posrefocus01 | posrefocus02 | posrefocus03 | C19Know | c19Hope | c19Eff | c19ProSo01 | c19ProSo03 | c19perBeh01 | c19perBeh02 | c19perBeh03 | c19RCA01 | c19RCA02 | coronaClose_1 | coronaClose_2 | coronaClose_3 | coronaClose_4 | coronaClose_5 | coronaClose_6 | ecoHope | ecoProSo01 | ecoProSo03 | ecoRCA02 | ecoRCA03 | houseLeave | houseLeaveWhy_1 | houseLeaveWhy_2 | houseLeaveWhy_8 | houseLeaveWhy_4 | houseLeaveWhy_7 | houseLeaveWhy_6 | houseActWant | houseActHave | bor02 | tempFocPast | tempFocPres | tempFocFut | neuro01 | neuro02 | neuro03 | para01 | para02 | para03 | consp01 | consp02 | relYesNo | godyesno | godOpinCtrl | godOpinInfl | godPunish | godForgive | trustGovCtry | trustGovState | ctrGJob | solMyCtr | solOthCtr | depressed | gender | age | edu | coded_country | ResponseId | wave | wave_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 1 | nan | nan | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | nan | 0 | 0 | 0 | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | True | True | False | nan | 1 | -1 | 1 | 0 | 7 | 7 | nan | False | False | False | False | False | False | nan | 1 | 2 | nan | nan | 4 | 4 | 0 | nan | 9 | 7 | 7 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 3 | False | False | False | False | False | True | 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | False | False | False | False | False | False | nan | nan | 0 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 10 | 5 | 2 | 4 | 1 | 0 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | 1 | 1 | 5 | Netherlands | d455fa2ff | base | Ongoing |
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 1 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | 1 | 7 | 1 | 1 | -2 | -2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | True | False | False | nan | 2 | 0 | 7 | 5 | 0 | 3 | nan | False | False | False | False | False | False | nan | 1 | 3 | nan | nan | 5 | 4 | 3 | nan | 3 | 9 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 3 | False | False | False | False | False | True | 0 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 2 | False | False | False | True | False | False | nan | nan | -3 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 1 | 10 | 10 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 3 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | 1 | 1 | 5 | Netherlands | d455fa2ff | wave1 | 12-3-2021 |
| 3 | 4 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 1 | 3 | 4 | 2 | 1 | nan | nan | 4 | 5 | 1 | -1 | -1 | 1 | -1 | 1 | 1 | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | True | False | False | False | False | False | nan | 2 | 1 | 7 | 7 | 4 | 3 | nan | False | False | False | False | False | False | nan | 1 | 2 | nan | nan | 6 | 5 | 2 | nan | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 3 | 3 | 1 | 3 | 1 | -3 | -1 | -3 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 1 | False | False | False | False | False | True | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 1 | False | False | False | False | False | False | nan | nan | -3 | 3 | 0 | 1 | -3 | 1 | -2 | 4 | 5 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 6 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | 1 | 2 | 4 | nan | 028a6e28 | base | Ongoing |
| 4 | 4 | 5 | 3 | 4 | 3 | 5 | 2 | 2 | 3 | nan | nan | 4 | 4 | 1 | 1 | 1 | -2 | 2 | -2 | -2 | True | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | nan | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 6 | 6 | nan | False | False | False | False | False | False | nan | -1 | 5 | nan | nan | 5 | 3 | 0 | nan | 6 | 1 | 6 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 2 | 3 | -3 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | False | False | False | False | True | False | 1 | 0 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 3 | False | True | False | False | False | False | nan | nan | 2 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 0 | 6 | 2 | 10 | 10 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 6 | 5 | 5 | nan | nan | nan | nan | 1 | 5 | 5 | Saudi Arabia | 4212d3a1 | base | Ongoing |
| 5 | 2 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 5 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 4 | nan | nan | 3 | 5 | 2 | 1 | 0 | nan | -2 | -2 | nan | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | True | False | False | False | False | nan | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 7 | 3 | nan | False | False | False | False | False | False | nan | 1 | 4 | nan | nan | 4 | 4 | 1 | nan | 8 | 5 | 9 | 5 | 5 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 5 | 3 | 3 | 0 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 3 | False | False | False | False | False | True | 3 | 3 | 3 | 2 | -2 | 1 | False | False | False | False | False | False | nan | nan | 3 | 1 | 2 | -2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 10 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 6 | 6 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | 2 | 6 | 6 | Saudi Arabia | 26dc23cf | base | Ongoing |
| 6 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 4 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 1 | 1 | nan | nan | 5 | 6 | 1 | 2 | -2 | 1 | -1 | 1 | nan | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | True | False | False | False | False | False | nan | 1 | 2 | 0 | 3 | 2 | 0 | nan | False | False | False | False | False | False | nan | 1 | 4 | nan | nan | 2 | 3 | -1 | nan | 6 | 1 | 4 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 3 | -2 | -2 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 3 | False | False | False | False | True | False | -3 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | False | False | False | False | False | True | nan | nan | -1 | -3 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 | -1 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 7 | 10 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 6 | 2 | 2 | nan | nan | nan | nan | 1 | 2 | 6 | Egypt | bed32257 | base | Ongoing |
| 7 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 2 | 1 | 1 | nan | nan | 4 | 2 | 2 | -1 | -1 | nan | nan | nan | nan | False | False | False | False | True | False | False | False | False | False | False | True | False | False | nan | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | nan | False | False | False | False | False | False | nan | -1 | 5 | nan | nan | 1 | 1 | 1 | nan | 9 | 9 | 9 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 5 | -2 | -1 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 3 | False | False | False | True | False | False | -2 | -2 | -1 | 2 | 0 | 2 | False | False | False | False | False | True | nan | nan | 2 | -1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 10 | 8 | 9 | 7 | 10 | 0 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | 2 | 1 | 5 | Morocco | 4sc2f1ae | base | Ongoing |
| 8 | nan | nan | nan | 3 | 3 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | 4 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | nan | nan | 1 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | False | False | False | False | False | False | nan | 1 | 1 | nan | nan | 10 | 6 | 2 | nan | nan | nan | nan | 3 | 3 | 3 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | False | False | False | False | False | True | nan | 1 | 1 | nan | 1 | 1 | False | False | False | False | False | False | nan | nan | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 9 | 0 | 0 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | 1 | nan | nan | Saudi Arabia | 3a86dadc | base | Ongoing |
| 9 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 3 | nan | nan | 4 | 3 | 1 | 0 | -1 | nan | nan | nan | nan | False | False | False | False | False | True | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | nan | -1 | -1 | 1 | 0 | 5 | 0 | nan | False | False | False | False | False | False | nan | 1 | 1 | nan | nan | 7 | 5 | 0 | nan | 7 | 8 | 7 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 3 | False | True | False | False | False | False | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 | False | False | False | False | False | False | nan | nan | 1 | 1 | 2 | -2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 3 | 5 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 4 | 6 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | 1 | 2 | 5 | Netherlands | 5d181ac9 | base | Ongoing |
| 10 | 3 | 2 | 4 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 2 | nan | nan | 3 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 0 | -2 | 2 | -1 | -2 | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | False | True | False | False | False | False | nan | 0 | -1 | 2 | 5 | 7 | 7 | nan | False | False | False | False | False | False | nan | -1 | 1 | nan | nan | 8 | 5 | 3 | nan | 7 | 6 | 5 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 3 | 2 | -1 | 0 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 1 | 3 | False | False | False | False | False | True | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 3 | False | True | False | False | False | True | nan | nan | -2 | -2 | 2 | -1 | -2 | 1 | 1 | 6 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 3 | nan | 2 | 6 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | 1 | 1 | 5 | Netherlands | d455fa2ff | wave2 | 16-3-2021 |

Comment: Adding a masked sample of your dataset would be helpful here

Comment: @Vaebhav I added a masked sample of the data :) thank you for your response!

Answer (score 1):

After copying your example data into a CSV file, I ran the code below. Note I've fixed typos and indentation, made sure the NAN values are recognized as such, and replaced `outcome_vars` (which wasn't defined in the code you posted) with two sample columns.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("data_path.csv", delim_whitespace=True)
data.replace('nan', np.nan, inplace=True)
p1_data = data.copy()

p1_scenarios = {"Dutch_Data" : p1_data[p1_data["coded_country"]=="Netherlands"],
                "World_Data": p1_data}

for i, scenario in enumerate(p1_scenarios):
    p1_data_scene = p1_scenarios[scenario]
    participants = p1_data_scene["ResponseId"].unique()    
    mean_per_id = p1_data_scene[['affAnx', 'affBor', "ResponseId"]].groupby(
                               by="ResponseId", dropna=False).mean()
    
    print(scenario)
    print(p1_data_scene.shape)
    print("Amount of participants " + str(len(participants))) 
    print("Shape of group per ID" + str(mean_per_id.shape))
```

The output is as expected in view of the fact that three of the Dutch response ID codes are identical, and the rest are unique:

```
Dutch_Data
(4, 128)
Amount of participants 2
Shape of group per ID(2, 2)
World_Data
(10, 128)
Amount of participants 8
Shape of group per ID(8, 2)
```

So for this dataset, the problem you describe is not caused by the code you posted, unless the choice of `outcome_vars` somehow affects the `groupby` operation, which it shouldn't.

Can you come up with a minimal data sample that does reproduce the problem?

Comment: Thankyou, good to know the problem is problably not within the part I was expecting. I added the preprocessing steps, which as a result would give the dataframe I added to the end of the post. Do you or anyone have any idea if I do something fundamentally dangerous based on the preprocessing code, which may cause this problem? I thought by using .copy() I would break any refference to previous views/data, is this correct or could that be the problem>